# Powershell Get-SPServiceInstance - The term 'Get-SPServiceInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell

On a fresh SP2010 install.

I run powershell as the admin

I have my policy set to unrestricted.

I've tried embedding this in a .ps1 file or running in the shell.. but get:

Powershell Get-SPServiceInstance - The term 'Get-SPServiceInstance' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

I've also tried loading microoft.SharePoint firrst and it did not help

Am I missing something here?

---

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to register SharePoint snap-in that contains the cmdlets by adding `Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell` before you call any SP cmdlets.

eg.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
Get-SPServiceInstance | Where-Object {$_.TypeName -eq 'Central Administration'}
```

will return

```
TypeName                         Status   Id                                  
--------                         ------   --                                  
Central Administration           Online   xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
```

You can also use SharePoint 2010 Management Shell:

- [SharePoint 2010 Products administration by using Windows
  PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806878.aspx#section2)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of just loading PowerShell, goto the start menu - all programs - sharepoint server - sharepoint management shell. That loads powershell with the Sharepoint addons.

Comment: This helped me, +1.